# IIFE chainable not returning correctly

Tags: javascript, return, chainable

```
(function (w, d, u) {
    /* Variable Conventions _*VAR*_ is html or class text*/
    var wl = '^\\/t\\d+',
    ps = '^\\/post',
    pv = '\\/privmsg\\?.+(post|reply){1}(.*)?',
    _GROUP_ = null,
    i,
    _CLASS_ = "sceditor-button sceditor-button-",
    _COMMAND_ = "data-sceditor-command",
    _TOOLBAR_ = "sceditor-toolbar",
    _MESSAGE_ = "message",
    _IFRAME_ = ".sceditor-container iframe",
    _BUTTON_ = "sceditor-button",
    _GROUPT_ = "sceditor-group",
    _TEXTAREA_ = "text_editor_textarea",
    options,
    interval,
    awe_debug = false;      

    var awe = function (opts) {
        var target = document.querySelector('#textarea_content');
        if (target) {
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
                mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                    var added = mutation.addedNodes;
                    for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
                        if ((/sceditor-container/g).test(added[i].className)) {
                            return new AWE(opts);
                        } else easyDebug("info", "AW Editor::\n No mutation on object, so there was nothing to observe.");

                    }
                    observer.disconnect();
                });
            });
            var config = { addedNodes: true, attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
            // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
            observer.observe(target, config);
        } else return false;
    };

    var AWE = function (opts) {
        this.instantiate = false;
        this.debug = false;
        this.commandList = {};
        this.pathname = w.location.href.replace(w.location.origin, '');
        var runAt = [];
        if (opts && opts.location) {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var loca = opts.location[i];
                switch (loca) {
                case 0:runAt.push(wl); break;
                case 1: runAt.push(ps); break;
                case 2: runAt.push(pv); break;
                case 3: runAt = [wl, ps, pv]; break;
                }
            }
        } else runAt = [wl, ps, pv];
        windowLocation = new RegExp(runAt.join("|"), 'gi');
        if (windowLocation.test(this.pathname)) {
            this.toolbar = getElement('class', _TOOLBAR_)[0];
            this.textarea = getElement('input', _MESSAGE_)[0];
            this.iframe = getElement('query', _IFRAME_)[0];
            this.instantiate = true;
            this.groups = getElement('class', _GROUPT_);
            var btns = getElement('class', _BUTTON_);
            for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
                this.commandList[btns[i].getAttribute(_COMMAND_)] = btns[i];
            }
            /*
             *
             *
             *  HERE IS THE ISSUE IT WON'T RETURN THIS!
             *  IF I DO return (window.extendAWE = extendAWE);
             *  It works but after a second
             */
            return this;
        } else easyDebug('info', "AW Editor::\n We couldn't instantiate AWE 3.4 please try again.");
    };

    awe.fn = AWE.prototype = {
        add: function (cmd, opts) {

        },
        remove: "",
        rearrange: "",
        id: "",
        destroy: "",
        insert: "",
        ajaxify: ""
    };  
    /*
     *  Next codes are functions to make awe faster and easier without using jQuery
     *  When editing ensure to use the debugger
     */
    function easyDebug(t, m) {
        if (awe_debug === true) return console[t](m);
    }
    return (window.editor = awe);
})(this, document);
```

My code above, in the `AWE` function it will not return this! I've minified my code to be a basic template for chaining and that works, but for some reason it will not return the way it is. I've tried everything and it's getting to be a hassle and a half now. I'm wondering if it may be my switch case? Can someone explain to me why it will not return anything, I've even tried for trial purposes `return true` I can `console.log` directly above it but it will **NOT** return anything.

```
var newEditor = editor({
    debug:true,
    defaultText:"How is going today?",
    removeWYSIWYG:true
});
//now that newEditor caches the returned object
newEditor.add('newButton',{
    //new button options
});
```

**NEW Observer Iteration**

```
var awe = function (opts) {
    var target = document.querySelector('#textarea_content');

    if (target) {
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
            var mutate = mutations[0].addedNodes;
            var ret;
            for(i=0;i<mutate.length;i++){
               if((/sceditor-container/g).test(mutate[i].className)){
               ret = new AWE(opts);
               break;
               }
            }
            return ret;
        });
        var config = {
            addedNodes: true,
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true
        };
        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(target, config);
    } else return false;
};
```

Comment: It would be AWEsome if you could shorten that code to something that still reproduces the issue :)

Comment: Oh I know it would be :) Nice pun btw. I will try and do that for you.

Comment: Hopefully that is short enough for you, don't want to take too much out and it being the problem altogether.

Comment: @Jack so I found out after realizing the best way was to start taking pieces out was to determine the issue and it is the MutationObserver.

Comment: When used as a constructor, the return of `this` is assumed; how is this thing called? Oh, called inside the observer ;-)

Comment: What do you mean? `return (window.editor = awe);` is how it's called so I'll update with the instantiation method

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to originate here:

```
mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    var added = mutation.addedNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < added.length; i++) {
        if ((/sceditor-container/g).test(added[i].className)) {
            return new AWE(opts);
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        } else easyDebug("info", "AW Editor::\n No mutation on object, so there was nothing to observe.");

    }
    observer.disconnect();
});
```

The return value inside the `.forEach()` callback is ignored; a regular loop or a temporary variable outside would fix it.

Comment: Many people told me not to use a loop. Can you show me what you mean by temporary variable?

Comment: @EasyBB Like, `var res;` just before you start the `.forEach()` and inside you would do `res = new AWE(opts);`.

Comment: and then outside of it do return res;

Comment: @EasyBB Yeah; of course, you can't prevent the `.forEach()` loop from iterating over the rest of the elements, though. This is why a regular loop is better because of better flow control.

Comment: oh I see a regular loop instead of `forEach` I see! I thought you meant a loop as a mutationObserver basically.

Comment: The MDN page on `.forEach` shows how to break out of the loop. Use `.every` instead of `.forEach`, and return `false` when you want the loop to end. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @Jack you're just full of it today LMAO ;)  oh and btw it's still not returning I must be doing it wrong

Comment: @EasyBB hmm, are you only interested into the first mutation btw? seems a bit odd somehow ... and I'm still not sure what the intended behaviour is supposed to be.

Comment: Well see the mutation happens after this code runs. I can't control that on the sites I am writing this for, so I am waiting for this mutation then instantiate this code. Which then allows us to edit and manipulate the text editor (WYSIWYG) that they provide. I'm just basically waiting for `target` to exist.

Comment: @EasyBB Hmm, then perhaps it might be an idea to call a predefined function from within the observer that sets up the whole apparatus :)

Comment: Ok I will try this, but it seems as though that is basically what I am doing... awe to call new AWE which sets up everything. maybe I am not getting the jist of what you mean